# error:failed to look up view "index" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

local host port served an error in browser and did not load my static files. Returned an error ***'Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\views"'.*** Even when i create a views directory for my static file, it still returns the same error. My node js version is v14.16.0 and i use a chrome browser. Please help!

stack trace errors

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\views"
at Function.render (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\server.js:22:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\contact form\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

my static file is inside the public folder named "index.handlebars". my node server code is outside the public folder
here is my package.json file

```
     {
  "name": "contact-form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "mahnuel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

my node server code is as such

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.client}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'site.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'email.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'password'  // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <email.com>', // sender address
      to: 'mail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.render('index', {msg:'Email has been sent'});
  });
  });

   
app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

Comment: What line is the error you're encountering being thrown on? Can you edit your question to provide the exact stack trace you're seeing per the guidelines on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: not sure if i even understand where the error is being thrown but i added a link to the repository so you could see for yourself

Comment: Unfortunately, as a matter of personal policy I don't tend to follow external links on this site unless there's a very good case to do so. If you feel there is specific information at that link that you feel is pertinent to your question here, you should edit your question to include such information. In accordance with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question shouldn't rely on third-party sources and instead "stand alone" - external links tend to break and change over time and deplete most all value for future visitors to your question. (1/2)

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace of the error you're getting in the body of your question? That *should* point to the problematic portion of your code. Finally (and slightly tangentially), I would recommend re-visiting your Node.js debugging fundamentals. (2/2)

Comment: Sorry about the back and forth. Please bare with me as i am still very much a noob. I have made some changes to the question and i hope it makes it a little clearer

Comment: Are you sure the snippet you've posted here is absolutely reflective of what you're working with? The error message you just posted ("*_dirname is not defined*") indicates you're attempting to reference `_dirname` (one underscore prepended) vs. `__dirname` (with two underscores, as expected). However, this discrepancy does not appear in the code you provided above.

Comment: I fixed the "dirname" issue, however, a new error occurred

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same error, but in my case I had forgotten the fact that the handlebars file I wanted to render was not index but was home.hbs rather. Sooo, just check if index is the correct page you want to render and if it is indeed in the root of the views folder.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

you may have made a mistake make sure your view file is in correct path like it check under src in my case i got similar error so i put views under src

You can customize the location of the views directory by providing Express with the new
path. Call `app.set` to set a new value for the 'views' option. The example below
configures Express to look for views in templates/views/.Version 1.0 45

```
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
app.set('views', viewsPath)
```

Comment: i added a image you van see that

Comment: When answering questions, please check your grammar to help readers understand your message.
Also, try to improve the formatting of your question (e.g., separating code from the rest of the text) to improve the clarity of your answer.

Comment: Thank you and sorry this is coming late. This seemed to solve the problem for me `const hbs = exphbs.create({
   extname: '.hbs',
   defaultLayout: null
 });`